# Scanning input in HashMap of String and ArrayList

Tags: java, graph, hashmap

I need to add all these cities in a HashMap of String and ArrayList

```
I/P:    Banglore Hyderabad
        Banglore Chennai
        Hyderabad Mumbai
        Hyderabad Delhi
        Chennai Kerela
```

And I am unable to add these , I have the structure

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main {

    public static void main() {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> adj = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>();
      
    }
}
```

So now i need to add banglore and then if banglore is present i will add Hyderabad to the ArrayList and again I'll scan for the next element again banglore is present so add Chennai to the ArrayList.

**There is already a question of creating a HashMap of String and ArrayList but firstly it is List of HashMap and Secondly no one there have shown how to add.**

Comment: have you tried `adj.put(*String*, *ArrayList*);` Your hashmap takes String and arraylist as parameters

Comment: as per description if you use **HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>** every string key will have its own arraylist as value, if i understand your problem, desc, you want to store single arraylist.

Comment: Yes at the end i want to store like (Banglore -> Hyderabad , Chennai ) ,(Hyderabad -> Mumbai , Chennai) ..... soo on like this but not getting an idea how to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
static void add(Map<String, List<String>> map, String key, String value) {
    map.computeIfAbsent(key, k -> new ArrayList<>()).add(value);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<>();
    add(map, "Banglore", "Hyderabad");
    add(map, "Banglore", "Chennai");
    add(map, "Hyderabad", "Mumbai");
    add(map, "Hyderabad", "Delhi");
    add(map, "Chennai", "Kerela");
    System.out.println(map);
}
```

output:

```
{Banglore=[Hyderabad, Chennai], Chennai=[Kerela], Hyderabad=[Mumbai, Delhi]}
```